# Does Windows provide drivers for most hardware?

Tags: windows, drivers

The last windows OS that I used was Windows XP. Now, that there are newer windows such as 7/8.1 and 10, I was told that I won't necessarily need to install Graphics or sound driver to be able to hear sounds and see graphics.

Does these edition of Windows bundle drivers for most hardware out there or is it just one generic driver which works with most?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely they meant that you wouldn't need those driver disks you usually get with hardware. Windows can provide generic or manufacturer/device specific drivers. However, it is best to go to the manufacturers website and get the latest driver straight from them for the best performance and stability.

This [post's](https://superuser.com/questions/657204/manufacturer-or-windows-update-drivers?rq=1) answer recommends using Windows Update to keep drivers up to date, but only if you don't care about the latest and greatest. It should also be noted that with Windows 10, driver updates are required and will install automatically through Windows Updates by default. More info on that can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/ad5a063e-5f57-c715-2566-b983195752c1/update-drivers-in-windows-10).